# Preselect an item in my dropdown with knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I have the following dropdown:

```
<div>  
    Dummy
    <select data-bind="options: categories, optionsText: 'description', value: 2"></select>
</div>
```

With the javascript below:

```
function ViewModel()
{

    this.categories = ko.observableArray([
            new Category(1, "Non classé"),
            new Category(2, "Non nucléaire"),
            new Category(3, "Classe II irradié"),
            new Category(4, "Classe III")
    ]);

    // Constructor for an object with two properties
    function Category(id, description) {
        this.id = id;
        this.description = description;
    };
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

I would like to pre-select the element with the id of 2 in the dropdown.

Any idea?

Thanks.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RfWVP/276/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two ways I can think of to do this. Either way you'll have to add a `selectedCategory` observable property to store track the currently selected option.

1. Use the `optionsValue` binding and specify `'id'` as the property you'd like to use as the `value` of each `option`:

   ```
   <select data-bind="options: categories, 
                      optionsText: 'description', 
                      value: selectedCategory, 
                      optionsValue: 'id'">                 
   </select>
   ```

   Then set `selectedCategory` equal to "2":

   ```
   this.selectedCategory = ko.observable(2);
   ```

   **Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/RfWVP/281/
2. Create the category with id "2" before creating your observable array of categories and set the `selectedCategory` equal to that category:

   ```
   var selected = new Category(2, "Non nucléaire");

   this.categories = ko.observableArray([
       new Category(1, "Non classé"),
       selected,
       new Category(3, "Classe II irradié"),
       new Category(4, "Classe III")
   ]);

   this.selectedCategory = ko.observable(selected);
   ```

   **Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/RfWVP/280/

Which one you use depends on what information you need about the selected category.